# Is $1 a usable token in Lex?

Tags: flex-lexer, lex

If I have:

```
if {
    yylval = $1;
}
```

Is this legal? If not, is there another way to say I want to reference what I put in?

(please dont say `yylval = 'if'`, it's not dynamic, and I want to use it in some more complicated scenarios)

Comment: If you don't mean `yylval = yytext;`, then I have no idea what you want to do. If you did mean that, no it's not legal because you need to make a copy, so you should use `yylval = strdup(yytext);`

Answer (score 1):

No. `$1` and friends are non-terminal or terminal symbols in the grammar. I don't know what you're trying to do exactly, but normally you would have a set of rules like this:

```
"if"      { return IF; }
"else"    { return ELSE; }
[0-9]+    { yylval.intValue = atoi(yytext); return INTEGER; }
```

etc., where IF and ELSE are defined in y.tab.h as a result of being declared in your .y file via the `%token` directive.

> please don't say `yylval = 'if'`, it's not dynamic

Neither is a `lex` rule. Your purpose remains obscure.